# asp.net ajax button fires non-ajax validator

Tags: asp.net, ajax, validation

I have an ASP.NET webpage with several updatepanels. I have a row of buttons (inside an updatepanel) which are connected to another updatepanel by async triggers.

Further down the page, outside any updatepanels, I have a filefield control with a few validators associated. The filefield works well, but when I call one of the buttons inside the updatepanel mentioned previously, it fires the validators associated with the filefield.

Is this supposed to happen? I thought that the asyncronious triggers only made a partial postback with respect to only the contents inside updatepanels.

Kind regards, Casper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to each button in the update panel, and change its corresponding property CausesValidation to False